# Is there a way to PREG a URL in Apache .htaccess without an internal or external redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How does one do string search and replace on a url in Apache .htaccess, to for example, convert:

```
http://host/x.jpg
```

Into:

```
http://images.host/x.jpg
```

BUT, without a redirect?  I want to be able to serve images from a unique host so cookies are not sent with them.  I've tried RewriteRule with the [L] suffix but it seems to redirect.

Comment: Can you enable `mod_proxy` on Apache server?

Comment: I don't have access to the server config.

Comment: Then this can't be done. If DOMAIN name changes then URL will be redirected.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  I can only imagine that there must be a good reason why this limitation is in place which is not evident to me.

Comment: I guess it is due to security reasons otherwise server can load anything remote in background.